# Do you believe that ASP.Net MVC is ready for production?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I really like the fact that Microsoft has taken a commitment to bring MVC to the Web.  To this end, I have become excited about converting one of my existing ASP.NET apps to MVC and wanted to know if I may be jumping the gun.  While this site is using MVC, it's still technically in beta...what are your thoughts?

Comment: Go with it. You'll be extremely lucky if you get the amount of traffic this site is getting.

Comment: How many different ways is this question going to be asked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Preview 5 to RTM, there will be less and less breaking changes. So if the concern is how much churn your project will face, it shouldn't be as bad as it was with earlier releases.

If the concern is support, we do ship the source code and you're allowed to modify (but not redistribute) the source for your own needs. In most cases, we've heard from customers that they didn't have to change the source to work around bugs, instead opting to use our extensibility hooks.

Answer (score 7):

Since Stack Overflow is written in asp.net mvc and it's in production, it looks like it's production ready :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is built on the foundation of ASP.NET (caching, authentication, etc) so it isn't having to deal with rewriting/stabilizing all those lower level pieces.

I have it in production and it has been very solid from a runtime perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I re-coded my site using the Preview 5 of ASP.NET MVC and I completely fell in love with it. I would not, however, convert any existing applications to it until it's in Go-Live. Too much could possibly change...

Comment: It is "Go live" right now, otherwise SO wouldn't be able to use it. It's still pre-beta, but it has a go live license.